# How do I make it so that the rectangle doesn't fall through the platforms? Without making the code too advanced or complicated (python 3 with pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

How do I make it so that the rectangle doesn't fall through the platforms? Without making the code too advanced or complicated (python 3 with pygame)

Here's the code, It's just supposed to be a simple platformer without any objective. Someone please help without making the code overly complicated.

Thanks in advance!

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((750,750))
pygame.display.set_caption("GAME")

x = 50
y = 680

Width = 40
Height = 60
speed = 6
ScreenWidth = 750
ScreenHeight = 750
jumpCount = 10
isJump = False


run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > speed: 
        x -= speed


    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < ScreenWidth - speed - Width:  
        x += speed

    if not(isJump): 
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
            speed = 8
        else: 
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False
            speed = 6

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (x, y, Width, Height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0), (100, 600, 300, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0), (300, 400, 300, 50)) 
    pygame.display.update() 

pygame.quit()
```

My post seems to be mostly code, so for that reason I'll just put this sentence here.

Comment: What error/problem do you have?

Comment: I have no clue of how I can make the rectangle stand on the platforms

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  This is really a great question about basic programming.

> How do I make a rectangle not fall through platforms. [In simple terms]

Let me answer the "without making the code [...] to complicated" first.

When you write programs, they're written to be as simple as possible.  If they're "too advanced", it's bad programming. Sometimes there needs to be a lot of code, because it covers lots of "Edge Conditions", and this tends to make the code *look* complicated, but really it's not, there's just more of it.

So: How to make a rectangle not fall through platforms ... first lets re-state the scope of work ~

> How do I make a rectangular object fall with a constant velocity from the top of the screen to the bottom.  It should stop when the lower-corners of the rectangle would hit any other object that resides in the path the rectangle travels.  If the rectangular object does not hit an object it disappears at the bottom of the screen.  If the rectangular object hits another object, it will come to rest on top of it.

While that description is more complex, it more fully describes the program to be written, and actually makes the design easier.

One of the great tools in the PyGame library is the [sprite class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  This library has support for rectangular objects with simple collision detection.  Typically people use this with a bitmap to fill the rectangle.  Now a PyGame sprite is a python `class`.  A class is an `object`, which is just a name for a collection of data and functions what have something in common.

Let's create one now:

```
class FallingSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = pygame.image.load("flower_pot.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, -50 )
        self.fall_speed  = 150 # pixels / second
        self.last_update = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )

    def update( self ):
        # There should have been movement since the last update
        # calculate the new position
        time_now    = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )
        time_change = time_now - self.last_update      # How long since last update?
        if ( time_change > 0 ):
            distance_moved   = time_change * self.fall_speed / 1000
            now_x, now_y     = self.rect.center        # Where am I, right now
            updated_y        = now_y + distance_moved
            self.rect.center = ( now_x, updated_y )
            self.last_update = time_now
            # Did we fall off the bottom of the screen?
            if ( updated_y > WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
                self.kill()

    def stop( self ):
        self.fall_speed  = 0
```

So that's a class for a falling sprite.  The `__init__()` function is special, and is called when creating the sprite.  It loads in a bitmap to represent the rectangle, and sets a few statistics about the object - like where it is on the screen, how fast it's falling.  One interesting thing to note is that we're using the system clock to determine the position of the rectangle.  It starts at the top of the screen, but each time the sprite's `update()` function is called (usually each frame), the `Y` position is increased (moving the object down-screen) based on the real time of the call.  The `stop()` function is used to cancel the falling.

So now we have a "falling rectangle", now there needs to be some "platforms" to block it (or not).  Once again we use the PyGame sprite object, but given this platform does not move (or change at all), it's a little simpler.  It does take a `position` co-ordinate as a parameter when it's constructed though.  This is so we can make a bunch of them at different positions.

```
class PlatformSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, position ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = pygame.image.load("brick_32.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( position )
```

Platforms don't move, so there's no `update()` function.

The next step is to determine when the falling sprite hits a platform sprite. Another useful function in the sprite library is detecting collisions.  In fact, it's possible to have a [Sprite Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) that can instantly determine if a sprite is colliding with anything in the group.  This is what we really need to know.  Whenever the falling sprite moves we need to know if it hit any of the platform sprites.

So we create a `pygame.sprite.Group()` to hold all the platforms.  We also make one for the single falling sprite, but only because it makes the program simpler.

To know if the falling sprite hit any platform sprites, it's easy to use the PyGame `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` function.  This takes a single sprite and a sprite-group, and returns a list of intersecting sprites.  This makes the collision detection too easy:

```
FALLERS.update() # re-position the flower-pot
# Did it hit anything
if ( len( pygame.sprite.spritecollide( flower_pot_sprite, PLATFORMS, False ) ) > 0 ):
    flower_pot_sprite.stop()
```

And that's about it.  The code needs to be wrapped in some other calls for handing user-input, and re-painting each frame of the screen.  But it's not a lot of code, and it's not complicated.

```
import pygame
import random
import time

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
# background colour
SKY_BLUE      = (161, 255, 254)


class FallingSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A falling flower-pot sprite.  Falls at a constant velocity in real-time """
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = pygame.image.load("flower_pot.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, -50 )
        self.fall_speed  = 150 # pixels / second
        self.last_update = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )

    def update( self ):
        # There should have been movement since the last update
        # calculate the new position
        time_now    = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )
        time_change = time_now - self.last_update      # How long since last update?
        if ( self.fall_speed > 0 and time_change > 0 ):
            distance_moved   = time_change * self.fall_speed / 1000
            now_x, now_y     = self.rect.center        # Where am I, right now
            updated_y        = now_y + distance_moved
            self.rect.center = ( now_x, updated_y )
            self.last_update = time_now
            # Did we fall off the bottom of the screen?
            if ( updated_y > WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
                self.kill()

    def stop( self ):
        self.fall_speed  = 0


class PlatformSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A stationay sprite"""
    def __init__( self, position ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = pygame.image.load("brick_32.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( position )

    def udpate( self ):
        # does not move
        pass

### MAIN
pygame.init()
WINDOW    = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Flowerpot")

# Add some sprites
FALLERS   = pygame.sprite.Group()   # a group, for a single sprite
flower_pot_sprite = FallingSprite()
FALLERS.add( flower_pot_sprite )
PLATFORMS = pygame.sprite.Group()   # a group for all the plaform sprites
for i in range(20):
    # create a platform at a random position
    new_platform = PlatformSprite( ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) ) )
    PLATFORMS.add( new_platform )


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )

    # Move the flower-pot, did it hit anything?
    FALLERS.update() # re-position the flower-pot
    if ( len( pygame.sprite.spritecollide( flower_pot_sprite, PLATFORMS, False ) ) > 0 ):
        flower_pot_sprite.stop()

    # Re-draw the screen
    WINDOW.fill( SKY_BLUE )
    FALLERS.draw( WINDOW )    # draw the flower-pot
    PLATFORMS.draw( WINDOW )  # draw the platforms
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )

pygame.quit()
```

[image: flower_pot.png]    [image: brick_32.png]

[image: animated demo image.gif]

Of course, being such a simple program, there's bugs.  For example: what happens when the falling object is falling so fast, so that it never exists in a colliding position?!  The upshot is that it can "fall through" a brick - at one point it was before the brick, the next `update()` it was already past the brick.  Woah.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. Little bit buggy but at least you're able to jump over the platforms:

[image]

Code:

```
import pygame

window_w = 750
window_h = 750

player_x = 50
player_y = player_y_min = bottom = 680
player_w = 40
player_h = 60
player_speed = 6
player_jump_count = 10
jump = False

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((window_w, window_h))
pygame.display.set_caption('GAME')

rectangle1 = 100, 600, 300, 50
rectangle2 = 300, 400, 300, 50
platform1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), rectangle1)
platform2 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), rectangle2)
player = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (player_x, player_y, player_w, player_h))

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]) and player_x > player_speed:
        player_x -= player_speed

    if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) and player_x < window_w - player_speed - player_w:
        player_x += player_speed

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and not jump:
            player_y += 1  # small hack to make this statement False: "player_y != player_y_min"
            jump = True

    if jump:

        if player.colliderect(platform1) or player.colliderect(platform2):
            if player_jump_count > 0:
                player_jump_count *= -1
                player_y += player_speed
            else:
                player_y_min = rectangle1[1]-player_h if player.colliderect(platform1) else rectangle2[1]-player_h

        if player_y != player_y_min:
            player_y -= (player_jump_count * abs(player_jump_count)) * 0.5
            player_jump_count -= 1
        else:
            player_jump_count = 10
            jump = False

    if not player.colliderect(platform1) and not player.colliderect(platform2) and player_y_min != bottom:
        player_y_min = bottom

    player_y = player_y if player_y < player_y_min else player_y_min

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    platform1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), rectangle1)
    platform2 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), rectangle2)
    player = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (player_x, player_y, player_w, player_h))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```